# Will the recent Intel graphics update be available for Maverick and when?

Tags: intel-graphics

with regards to the recent quarterly updates xorg/mesa/libva etc. Are they coming to maverick and when is this likely to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet will be to try the [Xorg Edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa).  This is usually very cutting edge material that will get you the latest and greatest graphics drivers.  Breakage may result when using this PPA, **so probably not recommended for beginners or critical/production systems**.

To add the PPA, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And cross your fingers...

Comment: yep cool, so far so good, i used synaptic and cherry picked what i needed. now for the 37 kernel, here goes!

Comment: Good luck.  What's your expectation from doing this?  Is the performance increase that noticable?  Intel graphics aren't going to be running many games are they?

Comment: just playing really, read there was improvement in the graphics and thought i'd give ago. its on an eepc, video does seem better from first testing tho, not as choppy as before. All running well so far. new bug in the logs tho, something to look into! Thx for info by the way.

Comment: Vote me up, bro!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that these updates will come through the normal channels, as they could break the system along the way. Chances are however they will be available for installation **at your own risk!!!** through ppas.

Answer (score 0):

If the update is minor (eg o.5.1 -> 0.5.2), it may come through SRU (Stable Release Update). You can also make a [backport request](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports#How%20to%20request%20new%20packages) but please read the criterias before submitting the request.